# typescript cannot find module in @types

Tags: typescript, meteor

I have an npm package written in TS:

test.ts:

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor'
console.log(Meteor.isClient)
```

this referenes:

```
node_modules/@types/meteor/meteor.d.ts
```

resulting test.js:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var meteor_1 = require("meteor/meteor");
console.log(meteor_1.Meteor.isClient);
```

When I use this package in another project I get an error:

```
cannot find module 'meteor/meteor'
```

The project using the test package has @types/meteor installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `npm i meteor-typings -S` and go to tsconfig.json, add the following

`"types": ["meteor-typings"]`

as a compilerOption to fix it. let me know how it goes.

Comment: it'd be @types/meteor now